# Looping through array and only getting last item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to loop through colors for my background with javascript but it only returns the last item, blue.

I've tried to look through different answers on this website but I'm new to javascript and couldn't understand what they are saying. Does anyone have an answer?

```js
function background() {
  const bg = document.querySelector('header');
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue'];

  for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    console.log(colors[i])
    bg.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  }
}

background();
setInterval(background, 5000);
```

```html
<header style="width:100px; height:100px"></header>
```

Comment: To clarify, are you seeing all the colors in your console (from the `console.log()`) or are you seeing only `blue`? Are you getting one output or four?

Comment: @klaycon I'm only seeing the blue when it shows up but when i console.log(colors[ i ]), all the colors show up in the console.

Comment: n-smits answer explains the problem, the other three give you code to copy-paste in. The reason this code of yours doesn't work as you expect is because each time the function `background()` is called (each time `setInterval` runs) the *entire loop* is executed. It sets the background color to each color, one after the other, extremely quickly. - each overwriting the last. So you end up with blue and only blue. If you want to *cycle* colors, you shouldn't have a loop running over all colors every time, but keep a counter outside and use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the console.log prints out all of them, but only the last remains saved?

**Because you're overwriting it inside the loop**, and loops run like instantly (or really really fast, no way you could spot that by eye). Meaning, because there is a for loop, the `setInterval` is not doing pretty much anything at all.

What's actually happening:

- *You're not doing:* 1, wait 5 seconds, 2, wait 5s etc.
- *Instead you're doing:* 1234, wait 5s, 1234, wait 5s etc.

Let's see an example solution in code:

```js
let i = 0;
// move variable i out of the function
// so it is not reset every time the function is run

function background () {
    // your code, nothing new here
    const bg = document.querySelector('header');
    const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue']
    bg.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    // then to have it change
    if (i < (colors.length) { i++; } // increase i+1 until we have reached max
    // i++ is shorthand for i = i + 1
    else i = 0;
    // and if have, reset it (that's why it is outside the function)
    // if it were inside it, it would reset every time the function runs
}
setInterval(background, 5000);
background();
```

Comment: Hi @n-smits, thanks for the explanation. I now know what is wrong.  I'm trying to loop through an array so that the background changes to the colors in the array.

Comment: @Alanaj That is what's happening actually! It's just that your loop doesn't wait between each element, it runs all at once, basically instantly. So it flashes between each color before you can see it, and ends on blue because that's the last element in the loop.

Comment: Yeah loop runs instantly (or like really really fast. Depending on the machine, but on today's machines really really fast). So you were going 1234, wait 5 seconds, 1234... instead of 1 - wait 5s - 2 - wait 5s etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hoping something like this-

```js
var colorIndex = 0;

function background () {
    const bg = document.querySelector('.header');
    const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue'];
 bg.style.background = colors[((colorIndex++) % colors.length)];
}

background();
setInterval(background, 1000);
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

**Note:**
The line `((colorIndex++) % colors.length)` means I declare an index variable named `colorIndex = 0` and increment at each interval and if it exceeded the colors array length then make it zero again by modulo it by the `colors.length`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your for() loop,

You are looping through all indexes of your array holding the colors and setting bg.style.backgroundColor = colors[i], but then the for() loop notices that i is still < array.length, so it continues to the next color near instantly.

Its only showing the last value of 'blue' since its the end of the loop. :) Your run condition of the for loop doesn't stop until it reaches that.

Maybe increment the array value instead of looping through it. Not sure of the best way to do that yet though.

(New to programming though, so listen to the other guys first, literally just made a Stack Overflow account 5 minutes ago haha)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the function without the `for` loop. Instead you can increment on each function call the indexer value. Once you achieved the last item, reset the value to zero and start from the beginning. So technically you can think about `setInterval` in this case like your loop but you need to handle the indexer value on each iteration.

Try as the following:

```js
let i = 0;

function background () {
    const bg = document.querySelector('header');
    const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue']
    bg.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
   
    if (i === colors.length - 1) i = 0;
    else i++;
}

setInterval(background, 1000);

background();
```

```html
<header>This is the header</header>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @norbitrial, this does work but can you help me understand the if statement.

Comment: @Alanaj Sure, Technically we are making an infinite loop by increasing the value of `i` until the `length` of the array. Once we accessed the last element of the array which is in this case `colors[3]` then we need to set the indexer to `i = 0` in order to start the loop from the beginning. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: it does clarify it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hi norbitrial, I was working with your code, and if you take away the - 1 the code still runs. Why did you have that -1 there, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the last one because you need to use the `setTimeout()` function or the `setInterval()` function. It only returns the last one because when it loops it goes all the way until the last one, without stopping.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to change the background color every 5 seconds? In that case use the below code snippet

```js
var colorIndex = 0;

function background() {
  const bg = document.querySelector('header');
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue']

  bg.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex++];

  //resetting the index to 0 to repeat the colors after reaching end of colors
  if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(background, 5000)

background();
```

```html
<header style="width:100px; height:100px"></header>
```